# Bounds on the smallest eigenvalue of a Hankel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $H=H_n$ be a positive definite Hankel matrix of size $n$ with $\lambda_n$ is it's smallest eigenvalue.
What bounds are known on $\lambda_n$ in terms of the entries on $H$.
I can see some results in terms of an underlying distribution and the entries of $H$
being moments over this distribution. What i'm looking for is a bound in terms 
of the entries of the matrix. If the bound is stated in terms of moments please give an explanation as to how to construct the distribution given the matrix.

Comment: For any positive definite $H$ with eigenvalues
$\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n > 0$
you can compute
$\Delta := \det H = \prod_k \lambda_k$ and 
$t := \mathop{\rm tr} H = \sum_k \lambda_k$ and 
deduce a lower bound on $\lambda_n$ from the AM-GM inequality:
$$
\lambda_n = \Delta \, \big/ \, \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \lambda_k
\geq \Delta \, \big/ \, \bigl(\frac1{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lambda_k)\bigr)^{n-1}
= \Delta \, \big/ \, \bigl((t - \lambda_n) / (n-1)\bigr)^{n-1}.
$$
I doubt that the Hankel assumption will let you do improve on this
by much if at all.

Comment: Thanks, however there seems to be a lot of works dealing with Hankel matrix $\lambda_n$  specifically. The conclusions there are in terms of moments. I was hoping for an explanation building on these results.